# How to compress memory space of h2 database ( in-memory mode)?

Tags: h2

h2 seems to take up too much memory space, How to compress it

Comment: I use the in-memory mode (database URL jdbc:h2:mem:test), because it is fastest. I hope that it takes up less memory, how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Do you use the in-memory mode (database URL `jdbc:h2:mem:test` or similar)? H2 uses a [pluggable file system / file system abstraction](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system), and as part of that there is are two in-memory file system implementations, one of them compresses the data. To use it, use one of the following database URLs:

- `jdbc:h2:memFS:test` (regular in-memory file system; a bit slower than `jdbc:h2:mem:test` but uses a bit less memory)
- `jdbc:h2:memLZF:test` (compressed in-memory file systems; slower than the above but uses less memory, maybe half or a third)

If you use the persisted mode: H2 uses quite little memory by default for the cache (16 MB), but you can reduce the cache size if needed (see the docs).