# Initialize H2 in-memory from a file contained in a jar?

Tags: java, h2

How to [initialize H2 with a file](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection) which is contained in a jar?

Currently I am getting this exception:

> testCase(CheckTest): org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception:
>   "java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /Users/user1/.m2/repository/a/3.10-SNAPSHOT/a-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/h2_db.sql
>   (No such file or directory)";
>   "file:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/a/3.10-SNAPSHOT/a-3.10-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/h2_db.sql";
>   SQL statement:(..)

The file I want to initialize the database with (`h2_db.sql`) is inside the jar file `a-3.10-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar`

The code looks something like

```java
initSqlFile = getInitSqlFile();
//initSqlFile = "/Users/user1/.m2/repository/a/3.10-SNAPSHOT/a-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/h2_db.sql"
//initSqlFile is a file contained ina jar, note the "!"

url = String.format(
      "jdbc:h2:mem:%s;MODE=PostgreSQL;LOCK_TIMEOUT=500;ifexists=true;INIT=runscript from '%s';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE",
       testSuitName, initSqlFile);

// later ...
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
```

Though this problem can be worked around relatively easily, I am wondering if H2 supports initialization from a file within a jar file.

Or perhaps an elegant workaround, which doesn't imply temporary files.

**Additional info**:
There is a method that looks up for resources, if the [resource is found](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) in the classpath the method returns the [resource's path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getFile%28%29). Then the resource's path  (`/Users/user1/.m2/repository/a/3.10-SNAPSHOT/a-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/h2_db.sql`)  is passed as parameter to the method that [initializes the database](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#execute_sql_on_connection).

Comment: @ThomasMueller Just edited the question. Btw, H2 is great!

Comment: With "what did you try" I meant: could you provide the source code you have used?

Comment: @ThomasMueller added some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As documented, the file name must start with the `zip:` prefix](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system):

```
zip:/Users/user1/.m2/repository/a/3.10-SNAPSHOT/a-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar!/h2_db.sql
```

Comment: Thanks.
I had already found the answer while browsing this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069224/how-to-compress-memory-space-of-h2-database-in-memory-mode/12071445